# Master-Detail Create Views in Razor, ASP.NET MVC 4 without javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create a Insert View for Master Detail, don't want to use any javascript, plain asp.net mvc, is it possible. tried to google but all exp are with jquery.

I just want asp.net mvc,

Just have 2 tables, **Person** and **ContactNo**

**Person structure**
PersonId,
PersonName

**ContactNo structure**
Id,
PersonId,
ContactNo

When create view load I want to allow use min 5 contactNo textbox so he can enter,

I tried to create the simple way I can, but its return Person Data, but contactNo is null.

Please help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PersonName)
        @for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            <input type="text" name="ContactNos[@i].ContactNo" id="ContactNos[@i]_ContactNo" />
        }
    </div>
}
```

You can add 5 default ContactNo. When you submit form you have got a Person with 5 Contacts. notice to the name of contacts **ContactNos[@i].ContactNo**.